# Dates In Separate Columns

Tags: excel, date, excel-2007, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

Is it possible, using Excel (currently have access to 2007 in our office), to make the data in Table 1 appear as it does in Table 2 using PivotTables or some form of conditional formatting?

TABLE 1

```
Mem Name    Mem Num Appt Date           Instructor         
Member A    123456  21/06/2014 10:00    Instructor A            
Member A    123456  22/06/2014 09:00    Instructor A            
Member A    123456  01/09/2014 10:00    Instructor B            
Member A    123456  04/09/2014 16:00    Instructor B            
Member A    123456  09/11/2013 11:00    Instructor C            
Member B    7891011 10/12/2013 08:00    Instructor D            
Member B    7891011 28/05/2014 17:00    Instructor D            
Member B    7891011 31/05/2014 14:00    Instructor D            
Member B    7891011 26/06/2014 16:00    Instructor D
```

TABLE 2

```
                Mem Name    Mem Num     1st Appt            2nd Appt            3rd Appt            4th Appt
Instructor A    Member A    123456  21/06/2014 10:00    22/06/2014 09:00        
Instructor B    Member A    123456  01/09/2014 10:00    04/09/2014 16:00        
Instructor C    Member A    123456  09/11/2013 11:00            
Instructor D    Member B    7891011 10/12/2013 08:00    28/05/2014 17:00    31/05/2014 14:00    26/06/2014 16:00
```

Essentially, we are an instructional facility looking to record the dates our instructors are seeing members for 1:1 sessions. Each member can have up to 4 appointments with an instructor and the format requested by the management is as per Table 2 but the data we can retrieve with our current skillset is in Table 1.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because I made a mistake on Table 1. It is now corrected. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

With an added column (in the example ColumnE containing:

```
=COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)
```

in E2 and copied down to suit) and a PivotTable seems viable. Say positioned and formatted as shown in the image:

[image: SO28342913 example]

Then selected, copied and pasted as values (in the example into G9):

The formula in J11 is:

```
 =IF(J3=1,INDEX($C:$C,MATCH($G11,$D:$D,0)+J$2-1),"")
```

copied across and down to suit.

Note that positioning is critical for the cell references in the formulae and that I have assumed sorting as in your example. I did not bother to change the labels for some of the output columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll put it into practice next time I'm in the facility and let you know. Much appreciated.